# Добрый день! Использую библиотеку react-google-maps. Как можно получить координаты центра карты?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-api, frontend, google-maps

Использую библиотеку react-google-maps. На зарубежных ресурсах информации мало. Читал, что координаты можно получить через getCenter(), но у меня не получается. Как реализовать в компонент кнопку, которая отправит координаты центра в родительскую функцию и как эти координаты центра получить? Может, знает кто? Спасибо!

Вот код компонента

```
    const Map = compose(
    withProps({
        googleMapURL: 
            "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB8ECfIjkNyE2AVBlG4Fpd4rD2Y4q5Ytpk",
        loadingElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
        containerElement: <div style={{ height: `400px`, }} />,
        mapElement: <div style={{ height: `100%` }} />,
    }),
    lifecycle({
        componentDidMount() {
            const refs = {}

            this.setState({
                onMapMounted: ref => {
                    refs.map = ref;
                    console.log(refs.map.getCenter())
                },
            })
        },
    }),
    withScriptjs,
    withGoogleMap
)((props) =>
    <GoogleMap markers={markers}
        ref={props.onMapMounted}
        defaultZoom={8}
        defaultCenter={{ lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }}
    >
        {markers.map( function (obj, index) {
            return (
                <div key={index}>
                    <Marker 
                        title="Hello World!" 
                        position={{ lat: obj.position.lat, lng: obj.position.lng }} 
                        onClick={props.onToggleOpen}
                    >
                        {props.isOpen &&
                            <InfoWindow onCloseClick={props.onToggleOpen}>
                                 <div>
                                     {obj.title}
                                </div>
                            </InfoWindow>
                        }
                    </Marker>
                </div>
            );
        })
        }
        <Polygon path={path} />
    </GoogleMap>
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В том месте где вы вызываете `<Map/>:`

1) создайте пустой объект `googleMap` (имя на ваш выбор):

2) передайте ваш `this.googleMap` в Map в props

```
export default class MapParent extends ... {

     googleMap = {}

     render() {
          return (
                 <Map 
                     // ваши другие props
                     googleMap={this.googleMap}
                  />
          )
     }

}
```

Тогда ваша карта будет доступна через `this.googleMap`

P.S: в `this.googleMap` объект карты попадает не сразу, а только через какое то время

Соответственно нахождение центра: `this.googleMap.map.getCenter()`